# How can I convert http code to https?

Tags: facebook, ssl

I want to add a chat box in my facebook fan page but the embed code examples start with http but facebook allows only https.
how i can change below embed code to https.
I m using iwipa application for page building.

```
<embed align="middle" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" flashvars="id=163365836" 
height="405" name="chat" pluginspage="http://xat.com/update_flash.shtml" 
quality="high" src="http://www.xatech.com/web_gear/chat/chat.swf" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="520"></embed><br />
<small><a href="http://xat.com/web_gear/?cb" target="_BLANK">
Get your own Chat Box!</a>
<a href="http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/go_large.php?id=163365836" 
target="_BLANK">Go Large!</a></small>
```

Comment: The chat box application must support SSL security. And your site must support SSL as well. Neither of these seem to be WP-specific issues, though ... I am migrating to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please show some example code? What chat box are you talking about?

Comment: It appears that there is no user Assad available to mark an answer as correct.  Please remove this question. As it is too localized for this one person.

Comment: Please check this url http://www.msdnonline.in/aspdotnet/how-we-can-convert-http-to-https-in-asp-dot-net.aspx [Click here](http://www.msdnonline.in/aspdotnet/how-we-can-convert-http-to-https-in-asp-dot-net.aspx) may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You will need to acquire an SSL Certificate and then set it up on your server.